# org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Bad version in readMessageBegin

Tags: cassandra, cql, apache-zeppelin, bigdata

I'm trying to connect cassandra with zeppelin. Every time I try to execute a query I get the following error. What should I do?

```
 %cassandra
select * from rawtweet1

org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Bad version in readMessageBegin
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:223)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_createInterpreter(RemoteInterpreterService.java:184)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.createInterpreter(RemoteInterpreterService.java:168)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.init(RemoteInterpreter.java:172)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:328)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getFormType(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:105)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:260)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:328)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the configuration of the Cassandra interpreter. I had to change it back to the default settings and than everything worked.